# Crear un fichero diferente en cada ejecución em c++

Tags: c++, archivo

tengo un código que almacena una cadena de caracteres que simula una dirección de una pagina, mi problema es que deseo además que en cada ejecución se  cree un fichero diferente que tenga como nombre la hora actual en el momento que se haga la ejecución por consola. Para esto tengo el siguiente código que obtiene la hora actual y además se lo asigna a una variable(por que así lo tenia pensado):

```
    char* dt = ctime(&now);
    cout << "The local date and time is: " << dt << endl;
```

El codigo que crea el fichero que guarda, en este caso, 3 strings:

```
//Para efectos practicos defino una variable que indique la cantidad de paginas a visitar
int cantidadPaginas = 3;
ofstream myfile ("direcciones.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        for(int i = 0; i  < cantidadPaginas; i++){
            cout<<"Por favor ingrese la direccion a la que quiere acceder\n";
            getline(cin,direccion);
            myfile<<direccion<<"\n";
            miPilaDinamica.push(direccion);
        }
        
        myfile.close();
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"No se pudo crear el archivo de direcciones";
    }
```

Todo funciona bien, excepto lo que antes mencione, ya que el código cada vez que lo compilo he introduzco las tres cadenas se sobrescriben entre si, entonces, quería saber si es posible que en cada ejecución se me cree un fichero distinto que almacene las 3 cadenas con la hora como su nombre. Intente con la variable pero por obvias razones lo que crea es un fichero con el nombre "dt.txt" que se sobrescribe constantemente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes obtener la fecha y hora actual con `time`, después exportas ese valor en una estructura `tm`, que tiene la información separada (horas, minutos, segundos, día, mes, año). Con esos datos ya puedes armar el nombre de archivo que tu quieras:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <fstream>

time_t now = time(NULL);
tm *ltm = localtime(&now);

std::string filename = "direcciones_"
                     + std::to_string(ltm->tm_year + 1900) + "_"
                     + std::to_string(ltm->tm_mon + 1) + "_"
                     + std::to_string(ltm->tm_mday) + "_"
                     + std::to_string(ltm->tm_hour) + "_"
                     + std::to_string(ltm->tm_min) + "_"
                     + std::to_string(ltm->tm_sec) + ".txt";

std::ofstream myfile (filename);
```

Comment: Te agradezco, me ha funcionado perfectamente, pero podrías darme explicarme que es una estructura tm en este caso?

Comment: @EiderYesidObando la estructura `tm` es una estructura que forma parte del estándar del lenguaje. Puedes consultar su documentación [aquí](https://cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/tm/)